# How plausible are RCTs/AB tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

Suppose that I wish to quantify the efficacy of a drug compared to a control. I proceed to construct my RCT (using sample sizes which guarantees a particular certainty and significance level). I also ensure that individuals of both groups are randomized of a particular population (say of individuals of a certain age range and of a certain range of severity of the disease of interest).
After finishing my trial, I conclude that the drug given to the treatment group had an effect wrt to the outcome of interest of 10% compared to baseline, and so conclude significance with p<.001.

Since the test was randomized, we can assume that if the groups were reversed (i.e., if the drug was given to the control and if the drug group was given the control drug) that the results would be quasi-similar, but is there any way of quantifiably knowing this? Since even two people of near-identical attributes do not react the same e.g. there are random biological processes which differ between individuals of identical attributes?

Comment: In the long run they would lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: The question isn't about biology: it's about randomization.  From that perspective there doesn't seem to be anything left to say: the results aren't just "quasi-similar:" expressed as a random variable, the two forms of the experiment are *identical.*